# Why Can't I Update new User Logged In Without A Refresh

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello I have an application that includes registration and login.  My issue is that when a new user logs in I have to refresh the page to get current user. I'm using interpolation on the template. I tried to use an observable but I get an error say subscribe is not a function. Can someone please point me in the right direction, I believe this will also help me with a similar issue with updating.  I have included a snippet of code.

Thanking You In Advance

Header Component

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit  {

currentUser: User;

  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public user: Observable<User>;
constructor( private msg: MessengerService, private cartService:CartService,private accountService: AccountService,private modalService: NgbModal,
               private productService: ProductService, private searchService:SearchService, private auth:AuthService)

   {this.currentUser=this.accountService.getUser()
    //.subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

   
     //this.currentUser=this.accountService.getUser();
     console.log(this.currentUser = this.accountService.getUser())
 }
```

Header.html

```
<button   id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false" ><span><i class="fas fa-user" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></span><p class="loggedin-user"><strong>Hello 
{{currentUser?.firstName}}</strong></p></button>
```

account.service

```
export class AccountService {
    private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public user: Observable<User>;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    )
     {
        this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User> 
        (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
        this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
    }

    apiUrl = '/users'

    public get userValue(): User {
        return this.userSubject.value;
    }


 login(username, password, email) {
        return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/authenticate`, { username, 
        password, email })
            .pipe(map(user => {
        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in 
                between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                console.log("Trying to get firstName", user.firstName)
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have both user and currentUser? If you just use user (with an async pipe) then you should be able to get the updates values after login.

Comment: I can't see the `getUser()` in the `AccountService` . Was it just renamed?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

The good part about making a MRE is that you might end up finding the problem yourself ;)
 And in case you don't, people can use the MRE to check where the problem lies.

Comment: Sorry I missed the copy paste:  public getUser(): any{
      return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));

Comment: I used currentUser because I got error when tried to use user?.firstname so instead I used currentUser?,firstname

Answer (score 0):

Rememeber: your services return observables, you subscribe (or use pipe async) in your components.

In your account service you has an observable "user" and a "userSubject"

So

```
this.currentUser=this.accountService.user
```

And you use pipe async

```
{{(currentUser|async)?.firstName}}
```

The function userValue() only give you the "actual value" but if change you need call again.

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a36hnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Faccount.service.ts)

NOTE about your code. Your Account service has an Observable "user" that emit a value when you "login" futhermore store in "sessionStorage" and in "localStorage" the JSON.stringify.

At initialize the service get the localstore and put in the subject, so, when you subscribe to the observable received this value. when login, the subject next a new value and the observable emit a new value